# Innodb Lock out causing whole database down

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have searched many threads and stackoverflow but I couldn't found any solution. I am trying to insert records into few innodb tables randomly rather one condition matches which cause whole database down. I am getting this error "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

One the question (#1103248) has been answered here

> In InnoDB, an insert on an
>   auto-increment column results in a
>   table lock. Selecting a row FOR UPDATE
>   results in a row level lock.

All tables are just used for inserts none of them table performs updated at all. My question is how do I avoid these locks? Is there any solution available?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about what your transactions look like?
For example, do you have multiple transactions in parallel inserting into the same table(s)?
It may be that you can alleviate the problem by changing the isolation level, or by serialising access to the database, but it's hard to know without a bit more detail.

Comment: I have disabled the transactions $mydb->query("SET autocommit=1");

and it is just one single insert, happens when page loads
INSERT INTO stats (id, sid, stats_time) VALUES($id, $sid, NOW())

Comment: There are a lot of different locks used typically even for a single insert, most of them are (hopefully) held for a very short time. On the other hand, selects don't (normally) hold any table or row at all, which means they should not block them out (but there are still internal locks in the buffer pool etc). You will need to see exactly what's happening. Can you produce this in a non-production system? presumably if you're doing things "randomly", it is a non-production system anyway?

Comment: Is id the auto-increment column on the stats table? If so, you don't need to specify it in the insert, just let mysql give it the next value, unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @Chris no, primary key is stats_id. I am trying to reproduce this error on non-production server perhaps i have to use some testing softwares.
Beside this I am considering innodb_autoinc_lock_mode not sure if it can help me.

Comment: UPDATE: I used url stress software and called the page with random data it worked fine on non-production server. Only few times it was unable to connect with mysql server this is due to over 100 threads and limitation of number of connections in mysql config.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I found.

- I installed the mysql 5.1
- I have put following variable in my.cnf innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
- Restart mysql all should be set!

Thanks every one for your help.